# What AI is best for learning an area

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, robotics

I have a robot that I need to write an autonomous program for. The program is to play on this feild: http://www.vexforum.com/wiki/index.php/Gateway.

and pick up the balls and barrels and put them in the cylinders(goals). I have sensors like light detection(best for following white line on ground or keeping track of location by noticing when you cross a white line), ultrasonic sonar, bump sensors, and encoders(count amount of wheel rotations). I want to make a program where the program learns the field and learns how to navigate best with the tasks at hand. I am thinking a neural net is my best choice but I can't think of what inputs I would use. The main thing is I don't want scripted paths. I know this is pretty vague but too much detail and no one would read this. Anyone ave any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Simultaneous localization and mapping (SLAM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping)
It is a pretty standard and successful technique for robot localization.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Udacity course 373by Prof Thurn at http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs373.

He has successfully applied 'particle filters' to program the Google Driveless car